# Inconsolata font not displaying fine in VS 2013

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2013

I was using the Inconsolata in VS2012 as it is a very nice font for programming.

But now VS2013 is not displaying it very nicely. See the image. It's displaying a bit smaller, a bit more roughly.
Any ideas?

[image: Difference in font]

**UPDATE**

I took another close look at the image at pixel level and I found that the characters are rendered exactly the same. The only big difference is that in VS2012 there is 1 pixel between each character, while in VS2013 there is no pixel in between.

Answer (score 1):

I'd raise this as a bug using the [Visual Studio 2013 Feedback tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/563d1003-f0ed-498f-8ef9-f8ee1aac39fe). You can install it from the gallery if you haven't got it already.

Answer (score 1):

I reported this same issue a few weeks ago in Microsoft Connect:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806254/fonts-are-blurry-stretched-and-faded-in-2013

I would recommend upvoting it and commenting that you are experiencing the same issue. I would mention the font you are using as well.